# Translating Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Given the following three predicates:

$A(x)$: $x$ is Emily

$B(x)$: $x$ is student

$C(x,y)$: $x$ is a book of $y$.

Translate the following sentence into a predicate logic expression:

Emilies' books are books of students.

My ideas: I had trouble to translate "Emilies' books", since knowing that would be easy to construct given sentence. I think using two universal quantifiers would help, but unsure on how to construct "Emilies' books" part.

Comment: $C(x,y)\wedge A(y)$ means $x$ is a book of Emily

Comment: @QED If I want to translate "$w$ is a book of Emily", is it correct to write $\forall(y)$($A(y)$  $\Rightarrow$ $C(w,y)$), since we have to use quantifiers to translate it?

Comment: @rentbuyer - It's bit awkward but it is correct. The assumption is that only one individual in the world has the property $A$ (being Emily). A more natural solution would be to use individual constants, i.e. terms that represent a specific individual in your domain. So, if $e$ is Emily, then you can translate "$w$ is a book of Emily" as $C(w,e)$. Are you allowed to use individual constants in you language?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I think if I was said to translate given sentence into predicate logic expression, I have to use some quantifiers there. So, in my opinion, $w$ is kinda a free variable, where $y$ have to be bound. So, I thought to use universal quantifier which really seems a bit awkward as you said.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Are there any alternative formulas if it is crucial to use quantifier? I think universal quantifier seems the only choice here, with conditional connective.

Comment: This is completely analogous to the horse tail sentence. Are you sure you have no idea how to construct the "a bood of X'es" part?